# Why does rotation $r^2$ by $\pi$ give an order $2$ subgroup in $D_8?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

Find a subgroup of $D_8$  of order $2.$

My attempt :

A presentation of $D_{2n}$ is $\langle r,s\mid r^n=s^2=\mathrm{id},srs=r^{-1}\rangle$, the reflections are $s,sr,sr^2,\ldots,sr^{n-1}$

Put $ n=4$ then $D_{8}$ is $\langle r,s\mid r^4=s^2=\mathrm{id},srs=r^{-1}\rangle.$

The element in $D_8$ of order $2$ are the reflection  $s,sr,s^2$ and $sr^3$ because they all are  identity symmetry

But there are $5$ distinct subgroup  of order $2$

Rotation $r^2$ by $\pi$ also give order $2$

Here im not getting why rotation $r^2$ by $\pi$  give order $2$ subgroup  in $D_8?$

Comment: That's not a representation; it's a *presentation*.

Comment: okss thanks for correction @Shaun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it twice gets you back to where you started (a rotation of $2\pi$), so the element has order $2$, and hence generates a subgroup of order $2$.